# Colored terminal output does not reset

Tags: c, linux, terminal, stdio

While writing a larger program I stumbled upon a small problem with colored text output. Here's a much simpler program that reproduces this issue.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define COL_RESET "\033[0m"
#define COL_BG_RED  "\x1B[41m"

char *str = "the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog";

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i = 10;
    while (i) {
        puts(COL_BG_RED);
        puts(str);
        puts(COL_RESET);
        puts(str);
        i--;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now this is what I get when I run the program:

**First time - expected result**

[image: first time]

**Second time**

[image]

As you can tell, the program decides to randomly print lines even after resetting the colors in red. When started in a fresh terminal it always prints the expected result. Unless I run `clear`, there is no guarantee the output won't be mangled like in the second picture.

In the pictures I'm using `xterm`, although other terminals do the same thing.

What can I do to prevent this?

Comment: is it possible that the issue starts to appear when the terminal starts scrolling?

Comment: Good point. This seems to be the case, actually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commented, this is known behavior for some well-known terminals: when scrolling (or reverse-scrolling), the newly cleared area on the screen is filled with the current background color.  Linux console does this (except for a glitch some years ago, noted in the [terminal database](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-linux2_6_26)).  [xterm does it](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_terminfo).

In ncurses, several related behaviors are lumped together as the `bce` (background color erase) feature:

- filling newly-cleared rows due to scrolling
- erasing the display, as well as erasing the part ending with or beginning with the cursor.
- erasing a line, or erasing the part up to, or from the cursor to the end of the line
- inserting (a blank) at the cursor position
- deleting a character

Normally ncurses fills in the blanks (and it is only a problem when the terminal entry is [poorly chosen](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#bce_mismatches)), and you would not see this.  But using plain escape sequences means that you get to explore the nuances of `bce` a little.

Terminal applications which use escape sequences directly for printing color should reset the color before writing *any* other text which is not intended to be colored.  Other applications (such as line-editing in shells) have to keep this rule in mind when erasing text within the line

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the issue occurs when the terminal starts scrolling.

The problem is probably caused by the fact that `puts` appends a new-line character. Modify your code by using `printf`.

```
printf(COL_BG_RED);
printf(str);
puts(COL_RESET);
puts(str);
```

Comment: I tried the same thing and wanted to reply with the answer, but it seems you got ahead of me. Thank you very much anyway.

Answer (score 0):

When I run this locally, I also observe some odd behavior.

**Using:**

```
#define COL_RESET      "\0x1b[39;49m" // reset fore/back ground to normal
#define COL_BG_RED     "\033[41m"
```

**Output:**

[image]

When changing my `#define` to use octal rather than hex I get a different (the expected) result.

**Using:**

`#define COL_RESET      "\033[39;49m"`

**Output:**

[image]

Also you may look into creating a macro for using `printf` with colors.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define COL_RESET      "\033[39;49m"
#define COL_BG_RED     "\033[41m"
#define COL_BG_NORMAL  "\033[49m"

#define COLOR_NORMAL    "\033[m"
#define COLOR_RESET     "\033[0m"
#define COLOR_BLACK     "\033[30m"
#define COLOR_RED       "\033[31m"
#define COLOR_GREEN     "\033[32m"
#define COLOR_YELLOW    "\033[33m"
#define COLOR_BLUE      "\033[34m"
#define COLOR_MAGENTA   "\033[35m"
#define COLOR_CYAN      "\033[36m"
#define COLOR_WHITE     "\033[37m"

#define COLOR_PRINTF(colorCode,fmt,...) printf("%s" fmt "%s", colorCode, __VA_ARGS__, COL_RESET)

char *str = "the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog";

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i = 1;
    while (i) {
        COLOR_PRINTF(COLOR_GREEN, "%s\n", str);
        COLOR_PRINTF(COL_BG_RED, "%s\n", str);
        i--;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Terminals probably don't like their escape codes directly at the beginning of a new line. Try Wouter's answer.

Comment: That does not really explain escaping hex vs escaping octal.

Comment: In the comments to the OP we concluded that the terminal behaves weirdly when the program causes the terminal to scroll. That's why the escape code should be at the end of a line, not at the beginning.

Comment: I understand that, however, I am not convinced that is exactly what is happening. If you look at my results above both instances would set the escape code after a newline. However, in the case where the escape code has octal presentation, it works.

Comment: I figured it out. Lame. It will not except the hex value if it has a leading `0`. As in `0x1b` vs `x1b`. This is using iTerm2 mind you.

Comment: `\x` is the way you put hex escapes in a string in C source code. It has nothing to do with your terminal which doesn't care what your program's source code looks like, only what the output is.